# Unix process fork hierarchy

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, fork

Need to implement this [this hierarchy of processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WAHv.png)

Each process having children must not terminate before its children. In
terms of messages displayed by the “info()” function, the END message of a
parent should never appear before any END message of its children. The info function look like this `info(BEGIN | END, process_no, thread_no);`

```
int main() {
    init();
    pid_t  pid2, pid3, pid4,pid5,pid6,pid7,pid8,pid9;
    info(BEGIN,1,0);

    pid2 = fork();
    if ( pid2 == 0 ) {
        // P2 child
        info(BEGIN,2,0);
        pid5 = fork();
        if ( pid5 == 0 ) {  // P5 child
            info(BEGIN,5,0);
            pid9 = fork();
            if(pid9 == 0){ // P9 child
                info(BEGIN,9,0);
                info(END,9,0);
            }
            waitpid(pid9,'\0','\0');
            info(END,5,0);
            // grandchild (of top-level parent)
        } else {
            waitpid(pid5,'\0','\0');
            info(END,2,0);
        }
    } else if((pid3 = fork()) == 0) {
        info(BEGIN,3,0); // P3 child
        pid4 = fork();
        if(pid4 == 0){ //P4 child
            info(BEGIN,4,0);
            info(END,4,0);
        }else{
            pid6 = fork();
            if(pid6 == 0){ //P6 child
                info(BEGIN,6,0);
                pid7 = fork();
                if(pid7 == 0){ //P7 child
                    info(BEGIN,7,0);
                    info(END,7,0);
                }
                waitpid(pid7,'\0','\0');
                info(END,6,0);
            }
        }
        waitpid(pid4,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid6,'\0','\0');
        info(END,3,0);
    }
    else{
        pid8=fork();
        if(pid8 == 0){ //P9 child
            info(BEGIN,8,0);
            info(END,8,0);
        }
        waitpid(pid2,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid3,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid4,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid5,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid6,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid7,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid8,'\0','\0');
        waitpid(pid9,'\0','\0');
        info(END, 1, 0);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){ 
        wait(NULL);  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My output is

```
[ ] BEGIN P1 T0 pid=4370 ppid=4122 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P2 T0 pid=4371 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P8 T0 pid=4373 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P3 T0 pid=4372 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P8 T0 pid=4373 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P5 T0 pid=4374 ppid=4371 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P1 T0 pid=4373 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P4 T0 pid=4375 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P6 T0 pid=4376 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P4 T0 pid=4375 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P9 T0 pid=4377 ppid=4374 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P3 T0 pid=4375 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P9 T0 pid=4377 ppid=4374 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P7 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P5 T0 pid=4377 ppid=4374 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P7 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P6 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P5 T0 pid=4374 ppid=4371 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P3 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P2 T0 pid=4371 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P6 T0 pid=4376 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P3 T0 pid=4376 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P3 T0 pid=4372 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P1 T0 pid=4370 ppid=4122 tid=1184286464
```

Expected output :

```
[ ] BEGIN P1 T0 pid=4370 ppid=4122 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P2 T0 pid=4371 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P3 T0 pid=4372 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P8 T0 pid=4373 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P8 T0 pid=4373 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P4 T0 pid=4375 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P5 T0 pid=4374 ppid=4371 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P6 T0 pid=4376 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P4 T0 pid=4375 ppid=4372 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P9 T0 pid=4377 ppid=4374 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P9 T0 pid=4377 ppid=4374 tid=1184286464
[ ] BEGIN P7 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P5 T0 pid=4377 ppid=4374 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P7 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P6 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P3 T0 pid=4378 ppid=4376 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P2 T0 pid=4371 ppid=4370 tid=1184286464
[ ]  END  P1 T0 pid=4370 ppid=4122 tid=1184286464
```

I'm trying to get at the bottom of this for almost 2 hours, but can't understand what is not going well, i think it has something to do with waitpid, but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you start all these processes, but you never *end* them.

Take, for example, the last `else` clause. Within that block, you call `fork` to create `pid8`. You then have process 8 print BEGIN and END, but then it **doesn't exit**, it continues on into the subsequent code, which is obviously meant for P1 (where it will pointlessly call `waitpid` for processes that it did not create). But also, it will blunder across the `info(END,1,0)` call. The same thing happens in several other code paths.

A few suggestions:

1. Only call `waitpid` in a process for exactly those processes created as direct children. Those are the only ones you can successfully call `waitpid` on anyway. For example, P1 cannot wait for P4, which it did not create.
2. Pass NULL as the additional arguments to `waitpid` *not* `'\0'`. (The latter happens to work in most C implementations, because the representation of the character `'\0'` is the same as the representation for a NULL pointer in those implementations, but it is not correct: you should be passing a pointer to an integer [or the special value `NULL`] not a `char` value.)
3. Check the return statuses on your system calls. If you had done that, you would have seen that many `waitpid` calls were failing. (That is not actually *causing* the problem in this particular case, but it's always a good idea to check for and print out failures, because they will clue you in to why the program isn't working as you expect.)
4. Most importantly, in each `if (pidX == 0) {` clause, after doing whatever else that block should do, put an `exit(0)` statement to cause the process to exit:

   ```
   pid8=fork();
   if(pid8 == 0){
       info(BEGIN,8,0);
       info(END,8,0);
       exit(0);          /* <<<<<<============ */
   }
   ```

Final suggestion: 
Pick a coding style and stick to it. You have

```
pid8=fork();
if(pid8 == 0){
```

and you have

```
pid2 = fork();
if ( pid2 == 0 ) {
```

and you have

```
if((pid3 = fork()) == 0) {
```

all in this same short program. That is, you're combining an essentially identical set of operations in different ways and then encoding them in the program with different spacing. That doesn't make any difference to the compiler, but it makes a lot of difference to humans trying to read your code (that will include yourself, if you write enough code).